# mongoose nodejs sort by data based on another collection

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, rest, collections

I am making an app with NodeJS and MongoDB using RESTFUL API. Android on the client side.

I have two collections: 
Images which contain

- user id
- title,description, image string etc
- array of tags (**tags: [{name: blah}]**

And User collection:

- user name, email, password etc
- array of tags ( **tags: [{name:blah, score: 2}**]

For every image that a user adds I add all the tags of the image to the user with score 2 if they don't exist or increase the score by 2 if the tag exists for the user.

I want to get all the images sorted by the user's **score** - for instance if the user has tags like that - {name: baseball, score:2},{name: soccer, score:4}
the image with soccer tag will be first and after that the image with baseball tags.

I tried doing that on the client side(Java) and it requires a lot of loops and inefficient code.
However, using GET I can't send the user's data (the tags with the score).
What is the correct way to do that?

Edit: I managed to do that by populating the user_id field in images schema.
Now I can get all images with all the user's data.
On the client side I am sorting the images by their user's score - looping the user's tags by their score from the highest value to the lowest and adding each image to a new list.
Then I add the rest of images to the temporary list and create the recycler view with it:

```
      List<UserTags> sortedUserTagsListByScore = userTags;
        Collections.sort(sortedUserTagsListByScore, new Comparator<UserTags>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(UserTags lhs, UserTags rhs) {
                return rhs.getScore().compareTo(lhs.getScore());
            }
        });
//        reverse user tags for ascending order
//        Collections.reverse(userTags);
//        loop all user tags
        for (int i = 0; i < userTags.size(); i++) {
//            loop all images
            for (int j = 0; j < imagesArray.size(); j++){
//                loop all tags of an image
                for (int k = 0; k < imagesArray.get(j).getTags().size(); k++) {
//                    checks if the tag of the image equals the user tag
                    if (imagesArray.get(j).getTags().get(k).toString().equals(userTags.get(i).getName())){
//                        for debugging
//                        imagesArray.get(j).setUpvotes(userTags.get(i).getScore());
                        tempImagesArray.add(imagesArray.get(j));
                        Log.v("sort","tag found :" + imagesArray.get(j).getTags().get(k) + " score: " + userTags.get(i).getScore());
//                        remove image and insert false image
                        imagesArray.remove(j);
                        imagesArray.add(j,new Image("REMOVE"));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
//        delete images that added to tempImagesArray
        for (Image image :
                new ArrayList<>(imagesArray)) {
            if (image.getId().equals("REMOVE"))
                imagesArray.remove(image);
        }
//        sort images without user tag by upvotes
        Collections.sort(imagesArray, new Comparator<Image>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Image lhs, Image rhs) {
                return rhs.getUpvotes().compareTo(lhs.getUpvotes());
            }
        });
//        add images without user tag to sorted images list
        tempImagesArray.addAll(imagesArray);
        imagesArray = tempImagesArray;
        createCards();
```